# Not able to update scope level property of controller from custom AngularJS filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display the number of record present in the table in the UI. But i am not able to update the record property present in the controller's scope inside the filter.Please help me with this.

```
<p>{{records}}</p>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Account</th>
            <th>Storage</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in (customerList | filterGridData:records)">
            <td>{{customer.display_name}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.storageStatus || "loading..."}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.state}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller -

```
$http.get(list.json).then(function(response){
   $scope.customerList = data;
   $scope.records = $scope.customerList.length; //use for displaying no of records in the table 
});
```

Filter -

```
 filterGridData(records) {
    // some filter logic on the customerList data and then the filtered data will 
    // be displayed in the table and also the updated no of records should be displayed
    records = filterData.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to change passed `records` value in the filter, because this is primitive value and primitive types are passed by value. Instead you should do something like this:

```
<p>{{filtered.length}}</p>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Account</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in filtered = (customerList | filterGridData)">
            <td>{{customer.display_name}}</td>>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You no longer need `$scope.records` anymore in controller and in filter.